# Wooden gate over concrete

Tags: gate-post

I am planning to put in a concrete widewalk around the corner of my house. I want to have a wood gate at the corner. Do I first put in the gate and pour the sidewalk around the posts or lay the concrete and attach the posts after.

Answer (score 1):

The posts for your gate should be embedded in a good concrete base 2 to 3 feet deep. If the gate posts are going to be inside the edges of your walk, then I would install them first. It goes without saying that you should use PT posts and be sure the top of the concrete around the post bevels slightly away from the post so water will run away and not pond around the wood.